# Does MySQL do UPDATE in place on NOT NULL column?

Tags: mysql, update

Assume I have a table like this in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
Key INT NOT NULL
, MyCol INT NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (Key))
```

And I execute a statement like this on:

```
UPDATE Foo 
SET MyCol = 13
WHERE Key = 42
```

Will MySQL do an INSERT followed by DELETE of this row behind the scenes (and thus, potentially cause a page split) or can the UPDATE happen in place on the row?

Under which conditions do each of these situations happen?

Comment: According to this [Advanced aspects of Inserting and Deleting data in MySQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/mysql_5_5_innodb_change), the clustered index updates can be done in place while the secondary index no.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube. Please add this as the answer and I will up vote it.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that the comment by ypercube above is correct :)  Here are some additional details:

- Updates occur in place, with the older version of the columns relocated to UNDO space.  The UNDO is used for providing [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), but also in the event of a rollback.  As InnoDB pages are initially written they are only 15/16ths filled, so there is some free space to reduce page splits.
- Indexes contain all 'versions' of a column.  This is required to be able to perform index-only-scans while still offering [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).
- Exception to this rule is overflow text/blob pages, which are always freshly written and not updated in place.